# Lenovo Ideapad Z370 - Power reated issues

Tags: power-management, lenovo, ideapad

I have a Lenovo ideapad Z370 and I'm facing some problems.

1. It consumes way more battery than it should, I got about 5 hours using Windows 7 and about 2 hours using ubuntu;
2. If I try to install bumblebee in order to disable Nvidia VGA controller it's useful since it stills turned on;
3. I've changed some grub configs and add some script that I found online to solve some of the power related issues but It's worse, after that when I unplug my laptop from power, it starts disabling my USB ports (not using any usb device that needs much power).
4. Volume hotkeys are not working properly, once you try to use them, unity fails at some points and you're unable to even shutdown your system.

Comment: OK on rest of the counts but please elaborate 2nd point. Is bumblebee giving trouble while installation or not working the way you want?

Comment: No... It is not giving any trouble while install, but when I install it 'apt-get install --no-install-recommends bumblebee', it should disable VGA controller from Nvidia, right? But it stills enabled, even after I restart my system.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I was following procedures for ubuntu 12.04 instead of 12.10. Nvidia GPU disabled and got about 5 hours of battery.